# Python: Why does return not actually return anything that I can see

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
def is_prime(n):
    limit = (n**0.5) + 1
    q = 2
    p = 1
    while p != 0 and q < limit:
        p = n % q
        q = q + 1
        if p == 0 and n != 2:
            return 'false'
        else:
            return 'true'
```

But when I send in an integer, there is nothing returned. The console simply moves on to a new command line. What's wrong here?

**EDIT 1:**
The following are screenshots of different scenarios. I would like to make it such that I call the function with a particular number and the function will return 'true' or 'false' depending on the primality of the number sent into the function. I guess I don't really understand the *return* function very well.

Also, note that when I send in to test 9, it returns true, despite 9 being quite definitely a composite number...should the if/else bits be outside the while loop?

Key to below image:

1: this is the code as it is above and how I call it in the Spyder console

2: adding a print statement outside the function

3: this is a simple factorial function offered by the professor

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX4hy.jpg)

**EDIT 2:**

I made a quick change to the structure of the code. I don't really understand why this made it work, but putting the if/else statements outside the while loop made things result in expected true/false outputs

```
def is_prime(n):
    limit = (n**0.5)+1
    q=2
    p=1
    while p!=0 and q<limit:
        p = n%q
        q = q+1
    if p==0 and n!=2:
        return 'false'
    else:
        return 'true'
```

Also, I call the function in the console using is_prime(int_of_choice)

Thanks for the helpful suggestions

Comment: for starters, fix your indentation. Then, run step by step, and look at the value of each variable at each line.

Comment: Because you probably need to print the return value presuming you even call the function.

Comment: I tested your code with an additional print statement and everything works fine with the exception of `n=1`.

Comment: Your function would return None if it doesn't enter the loop. It really isn't clear what is the issue. Show us how you run your code.

Comment: As long as the number is 2 or more, it works for me _when run interactively in the interpreter_.

Comment: if None == is_prime(0): print ("the return value was None because the function finished without getting to a return statement")

Comment: The last four lines of code can be written more pythonically as: `return p == 0 and n!=2` where the conditional evaluates to a boolean `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print something to the console you have to use a print statement. The return keyword means that you can use this value in a piece of code that calls this function. So to print something:

```
print (x)
```

For more information about the print statement see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong, but you have to print out the return of your function.
Like this:

```
def Test():
    if True:
        return "Hi"

print(Test())
```

In this case python will show "Hi" in your console.